# Indent second line of UILabel (swift)

Tags: swift

```
var testLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(8,0,tableView.frame.width-8,100))
let testDesc = "dsfdddfdsfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf"
var labelString = indexString + ".    " + testDesc
testLabel.text = labelString
testLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
retCell.addSubview(testLabel)
```

My output:

```
1.    ksajdkasdsajdksajdksajd
asjdkjassadkasldkalsdklsakdl
```

How can make my output like the following:

```
1.    asdasdasdasdasdasdasds
      djaskdjsadjksadasjdjas
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is the code that I used

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
paragraph.headIndent = 8 //You can change this to whatever indent you want

let mutString = NSAttributedString(
    string: "this is a test but I need this to be long so it flows onto multiple lines so I will keep going",
    attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraph]
)

mainLabel.attributedText = mutString
```

Comment: Thanks for helping someone learn, and not being jerk about it.

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 6):

Make an attributed string (NSMutableAttributedString) and set its paragraph style's `firstLineHeadIndent` and `headIndent` as desired. Now set the label's `attributedText` to that attributed string.